# Why doesn't the input[type=range] work after CSS3 transform?

Tags: ios, css, input, mobile-safari, transform

**Must use the JSFiddle on iOS to see issue :)**

Developing an iOS web app, and have multi panels which are translated -480px on click (by adding a class with JQuery).

When I use `-webkit-transform: translate: (480px,0);` on the first navigation button, everything is fine except the input[type=range] becomes unresponsive.

I originally had this: http://jsfiddle.net/b4ung/2/

And later I added `-webkit-perspective: 1;` to the body. This fixed on Safari but ***not*** on **iOS**: http://jsfiddle.net/RLywz/2/embedded/result/

Can someone please tell me how to get the range function to work on iOS, and why it doesn't register after the translation?

---

Just for further note, if I change the transform to "left: -480px" the range works, but then becomes blocky when animating.

Any light would be tops, as its quite annoying (and if its a bug can someone file it 'cause I'm not a developer)

---

***Edited to make the problem more clear, and show updated JSFiddle***

Comment: Seems to run perfectly for me (at least in chrome). Could you be a bit more specifif about your browser/OS?

Comment: The slider looks before AND after the `moveY()` fine to me... And where is the `showValue()` function?

Comment: i can see problem in firefox....Will try solving it...

Comment: yeah it looks fine, but under Safari, and iOS the slider doesn't work.

The showValue is for another part where the value is just written into the document.

Any hacks for it to work on iOS?

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-range can give you a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I was able to hack it by setting the panel's css property to translate(0,0) when it needs to have the range working.
In order to have the animation/position right, I wrapped the element with a div and set the x position as needed and shifted the panel's translate property when the range doesn't need to be active. Hope it works in your structure.